# Different xtick distance for different x ranges

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I created a graph using `tikz`, which ranges from -10 to 10 for the `xaxis`.

The graph has an `xtick distance` of 2, but I want to change the `xtick distance` so I get this: `-10,-5,0,2...10`.
From `-10 to 0`, I want steps of 5, and from `0 to 10`, I want steps of 2.

Is this possible to do?

I have added my code as well.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-10, xmax = 10,ymin=0,
    xtick distance=2,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$Error$,
    title = {Output Error},
    ]
    \addplot [mark=none,color=orange] table[x=x,y=error,col sep=comma]{./output_error.csv};         
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You can just punch in what you want to get: `xtick={-10,-5,0,2,4,...,10}`. Obviously I do not have your data file.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-10, xmax = 10,ymin=0,
    xtick={-10,-5,0,2,4,...,10},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=Error,
    title = {Output Error},
    ]
    \addplot [mark=none,color=orange] {x};
    %table[x=x,y=error,col sep=comma]{./output_error.csv};         
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This did the trick, but in a general case is it still possible to have different xtick distance for different ranges.

Comment: @user94758 I believe it is possible but do not think that the resulting syntax will be simpler than the above.